# How can I take contents of one element and add to another when they both have an id ending in the same two or three digit number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.update-title')
    .change(function () {
        $(this).prop('title', $('option:selected', this).prop('title'));
    });
```

and this HTML:

```
<select id="modal_TempRowKey_14" class="update-grid update-title">
...
...
</select>

<input id="modal_Title_14" class="update-grid" type="text" value="xx">
```

Is it possible for me to make it so that when the .update-title changes 
then the value of the title is put into the input id with the matching number. 
So in this case the `#modal_TempRowKey_14` title would go into `#modal_Title_14` value

**Important**

I want this to happen only if the element being changed starts with `modal_TempRowKey`. Is this possible to put into the change block?

Comment: Of course this is possible.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.update-title').on("change", function() {
    var id = this.id.replace('modal_TempRowKey_', '');  
    $("#modal_Title_" + id).val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, rather than trying to parse `id` attributes, is to make use of jQuery's `data` function.

Edit your HTML so that the `select` menu has a `data-target` attribute:

```
<select id="modal_TempRowKey_14" data-target="#modal_Title_14" class="update-grid update-title">
...
...
</select>
```

Then, create your event handler like so:

```
$('.update-title').on('change',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $($this.data('target')).val($this.val());
})
```

You use the `data-target` attribute to find the element to which you want to apply the `select` menu's value.

Here's a demo:

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/vWS2G/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.update-title').change(function () {
    var m = this.id.match(/^modal_TempRowKey_(\d+)$/);
    if (m) {
        $("#modal_Title_" + m[1]).val(this.id);
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kqQJv/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Others have a more elegant approach, here is my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/8sLCL/1/

```
$('.update-title')
    .change(function () {
        var my_text = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        var my_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var my_num_pos = my_id.lastIndexOf("_");
        var my_num = my_id.substr(my_num_pos + 1 ,my_id.length - my_num_pos  );
        $( "#modal_Title_" + my_num ).val(my_text );
});​
```